# Is it possible to create a general forecast model working on several data sets?

Tags: forecasting, arima, exponential-smoothing, automatic-algorithms

I am working on a project, where the task is to create forecast models that can be used on a wide variaty of data sets. Some of which are stationary and some which aren't. Both ARIMA and Exponential Smoothing is considered using the auto.arima and ETS functions to choose good models. What is the best approach to achieving "decent" forecasts for several very different data sets?

Comment: This is investigated in the various M competitions, M4 being the latest edition. The results of `forecast::auto.arima`, `forecast::ets` and the combination of both are discussed in the context of M3 here: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/show-me-the-evidence/

Comment: An alternative that has gotten a lot of consideration is averaging different models such as arima and esm into one prediction. There is evidence this improves the results. You might find this interesting https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast-combinations/